# Emacs -- remove an overlay `after-string` with a variable value

Tags: emacs, elisp

What is the proper way, please, to remove `after-string` overlays with variable values?

When using `C-u C-x =`, it only shows up as `after-string` without stating what the value is.

For example, once I lay an overlay using `(overlay-put (make-overlay (point) (point)) 'after-string my-concatenated-string)`, I would like to be able to delete it without programming Emacs to remember every single `my-concatenated-string` that was previously used in the buffer -- there might be a few different ones on every line?

Is it sufficient to use?:  `(remove-overlays (window-start) (window-end)) 'after-string)`

Or, is it better to use?:  `(remove-overlays (window-start) (window-end)) 'after-string t)`

Or, is there another method to get them all?

---

**EDIT** (March 17, 2014):  My confusion is apparently coming from a misunderstanding between an *object* and a *property*.

In general, an overlay *property* is created as follows:

```
(overlay-put (make-overlay (point) (point)) 'my-property 'property-number-one )
```

In general, an overlay *object* is created as follows:

```
(overlay-put (make-overlay (point) (+ (point) 1))
  'face '(:background "gray50" :foreground "black"))
```

Here is a unique situation where an `'after-string` smells-like an *object*.  My assumption is:  if it smells-like an *object*, then perhaps a *value* needs to be included when attempting to remove it so that I'm not left with a *disconnected* `'after-string`:

```lisp
(save-excursion
  (end-of-line)
  (let ((eol-floating-column (+ (current-column) 10)))
    (overlay-put (make-overlay (point) (point))
                 'after-string
                 (concat
                  (propertize (char-to-string ?\uE001)
                              'display
                              `((space :align-to ,eol-floating-column)
                                (space :width 0)))
                  (propertize (char-to-string ?\u00B6)
                              'face '(:background "gray50" :foreground "black")
                              'cursor t) ))))
```

Comment: `make-overlay` creates an overlay object.  `overlay-put` then adds a property to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lisp
(defun lawlist-remove-overlays (beg end name val)
  "Remove the overlays."
  ;; DEBUGGING
  ;; (unless (and beg end name val)
  ;;   (message "ERROR -- beg:  %s | end:  %s | name:  %s | val:  %s" beg end name val))
  (let* (
      (point-max (point-max))
      (point-min (point-min))
      (narrowed-p (not (equal (- point-max point-min) (buffer-size))))
      (beg (if beg beg point-min))
      (end
        (cond
          ((and
              (not narrowed-p)
              end)
            end)
          ((and
              (not narrowed-p)
              (null end))
            point-max)
          ((and
              narrowed-p
              end
              (< end point-max))
            end)
          ((and
              narrowed-p
              end
              (= end point-max))
            (1+ end))
          ((and
              narrowed-p
              (null end))
            (1+ point-max)) )))
    (when (and beg end name val)
      (overlay-recenter end)
      (dolist (o (overlays-in beg end))
        (when (eq (overlay-get o name) val)
          (delete-overlay o))))))

  (dolist (description `(
    ,fci-pre-limit-string
    ,fci-pre-limit-active-region-string
    ,fci-at-limit-string
    ,fci-post-limit-string
    ,fci-wrapped-limit-string
    ,fci-cursor-at-eol-string
    ,fci-tab-text-left
    ,fci-tab-text-right
    ,fci-tab-sandwiched))
  (lawlist-remove-overlays nil nil 'after-string description))
```

See also this related thread which deals with targeting overlays with values containing text properties:

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/9847/2287

Answer (score 2):

The way the code is written, if you omit the last parameter, it only removes an overlay if the value is `nil' (which it doesn't appear to be in your case).

As you don't know the value of the property, I don't think you can use the function. However, you can simply write something like (assuming the value of the `after-string` is never nil):

```
    (dolist (o (overlays-in (window-start) (window-end)))
      (when (overlay-get o 'after-string)
        (delete-overlay o))
```

Also note that if you do this from a post-command hook, `window-end` might not reflect the true value. To be safe you can do `(window-end nil t)`, however this could be a bit slower.

Answer (score 1):

When you put the overlay, add another property (like `(overlay-put ol 'lawlist t)`, for example), after which you can remove those overlays with `(remove-overlays BEG END 'lawlist t)`.

Comment: Will removing `lawlist t` leave *disconnected* `after-string my-concatenated-string`, or will it get rid of the `after-string . . .`?  Earlier in the week, I had an ever increasing pile of *disconnected* overlays gumming up the works because I was using `delete-overlay` instead of `remove-overlays` -- I want to remove `after-string . . .` entirely, instead of merely *disconnecting* it.

Comment: Please read the Elisp manual about overlays.  `remove-overlays`, like `delete-overlay` operates on *overlays* not on their *properties*.  When you delete/remove an overlay, it keeps all its properties, but they're not applied to the text any more (i.e. all its properties are "removed" from the text).

Comment: `remove-overlay` calls `delete-overlay` (unless it moves one of the ends), so you will not gain anything by using it.

Comment: Thank you Stefan and @Lindydancer -- I'll work on it this weekend and see if I can gain a better understanding regarding *disconnecting* an `after-string` **object** versus *removing* an `after-string` **object**.  My assumption is that `after-string my-concatenated-string` is an **object** (e.g., a visible rectangular bar with a background and a foreground), *not* a **property**.  My assumption is that `delete-overlay` *disconnects* an **object** but does *not* remove it; whereas, `remove-overlays` gets rid of the **object** entirely (instead of merely *disconnecting* it, it is gone for good)

Comment: There is no such thing as "an after string object".  And there is no useful difference between `delete-overlay` and `remove-overlays` in this respect either.

Comment: Would it be accurate to state that the following is a **property**?  `(overlay-put (make-overlay (point) (point)) 'after-string (propertize (char-to-string ?\u00B6) 'face '(:background "gray50" :foreground "black") 'cursor t) )`

Comment: @Lindydancer and Stefan:  I've updated the question with three examples to help explain my confusion regarding what this special circumstance `after-string` is (i.e., what do we call it), and how to remove it properly.  Perhaps the answer is simply that -- even though it smells like an *object*, it is not in fact an *object*.

Comment: @lawlist, Just to make sure, if you create an overlay with both the `face` and your own property, say, `my-property` -- are you sure that you add them to the *same* overlay object? In other words, there should be *one* call to `make-overlay` and *two* calls to `overlay-put`. Something like `(let ((o (make-overlay ...))) (overlay-put o 'face ...) (overlay-put o 'my-property ...))`

Comment: If you make a single call to make-overlay, then yes, you add them to the same overlay object.  And that's what we want.