# Remove all fontlock faces (except flyspell-incorrect flyspell-duplicate)

Tags: emacs, elisp, font-lock

To shave off approximately `.3` seconds from the run-time of a custom function that is set with a 2 second idle timer (which custom function combs through the buffer), I disable font-lock mode with `(font-lock-mode -1)`.  The side effect is that my `flyspell-incorrect` and `flyspell-duplicate` get removed.  To put those flyspell fonts back again with `(flyspell-region (window-start) (window-end))` costs *a lot more than* `.3` seconds.  So, I was thinking of a midway ground by removing all the font-lock fonts *except* `flyspell-incorrect` and `flyspell-duplicate`.  Is there a way to add a condition to the following code snippet from `font-core` that will preserve the flyspell fonts, yet remove everything else?

```
;; Turn off Font Lock mode.

(unless mode
  ;; Remove `font-lock-face' as an alias for the `face' property.
  (set (make-local-variable 'char-property-alias-alist)
 (copy-tree char-property-alias-alist))
  (let ((elt (assq 'face char-property-alias-alist)))
    (when elt
(setcdr elt (remq 'font-lock-face (cdr elt)))
(when (null (cdr elt))
  (setq char-property-alias-alist
  (delq elt char-property-alias-alist))))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my surprise, it turned out that flyspell uses **overlays**, *not* font-lock.  My problem occurred because I improperly used `remove-overlays` by failing to include a precise value that existed.  Improper usage of `remove-overlays` removes the whole kitten-kaboodle in the region -- including flyspell overlays.  The following related thread describes how to avoid this problem by ensuring that a correct value is always included when using `remove-overlays` if a value exists:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23773934/2112489

Here is a helpful little function to see what is going on behind the scenes:

```lisp
(defun reveal-overlays (&optional beg end)
(interactive)
  (let* (
      (beg (if beg beg (window-start)))
      (end (if end end (window-end))))
    (overlay-recenter end)
    (dolist (o (overlays-in beg end))
      (when o
        (message "%s\n%s\n" (overlay-properties o) o)))
    (switch-to-buffer "*Messages*")))
```

Answer (score 0):

`(font-lock-mode -1)` does not remove the flyspell-incorrect and flyspell-duplicate thingies.  It just disables their visual effect (with the code that you posted).  So you can re-set `char-property-alias-alist` afterwards and those flyspell thingies will "instantly" be displayed again.

I do wonder what it is you're doing that is slowed down by 0.3 seconds by font-lock.  Maybe there's another way to avoid those 0.3 seconds than `(font-lock-mode -1)` since enabling/disabling font-lock is very expensive.

Comment: I have a working draft of a vertical line highlighter that tracks my cursor position in `visual-line-mode`.  It goes through the buffer two (2) times between `window-start` and `window-end`.  The first pass is with `re-search-backward "\n" . . .`  The second pass is with `vertical-motion -1`.  The first pass places overlays at all line endings (e.g., hard returns), and also on every *first* line (until window end).  The second pass places overlays on the word-wrapped area according to the `visual-line-mode` layout.  The run-time is *twice* as long with font-lock-mode in a `tex-mode` buffer.

Comment: I have made significant improvements to the run-time by performing the calculations just once at the outset of each `re-search-backward` and each `vertical-motion -1`.  This morning I ran a new test with my improved code and verified the run-time is still *double* with `font-lock-mode` enabled.  Admittedly, however, the run-time is now much less than `.3` -- I have it down to approximately `.08` to `.12` with `(font-lock-mode -1)`.  With `(font-lock-mode 1)`, the run time is *double* -- i.e., `.16` to `.24`.  I'm *not* using `AUCTeX`.  I use `tex-mode.el` with some added keywords.

Comment: How do you add the visual effects?  If you do by modifying the buffer (e.g. put-text-property), then indeed font-lock will slow it down unless you use `with-silent-modifications`.

Comment: I discovered today that using `remove-overlays` with a **name**, but *without* a specific **value** following the **name**, has the effect of removing **ALL** overlays.  That was the root cause of my flyspell markings being removed.  For some reason, I had erroneously thought that flyspell was font-lock -- instead, flyspell uses overlays.  All of my vertical line visual effects are being created with `(overlay-put (make-overlay (point) (point)) 'after-string value)`; or by using point and point + 1 with `'display variable-character`; or by using `'face variable-face`; or with `'invisible t`.